# X-Files "Gender Bender" - What is the song?

Tags: music-identification, the-x-files

In X-Files S1E14 "Gender Bender" the show starts off in a club of some kind with what I can only describe as a very grunge-sounding type of electronic music or deep house. Amused, I tried to Shazam it but that didn't return any matches.

I was really hoping the search would lead me to some obscure 90's DJ. From which point I could learn more about him/her. Then I got to thinking, maybe it's proprietary X-Files music. In which case, I'm not sure if there is a place to listen to it.

Comment: If it's in X-Files and electronic in nature, it's pretty much guaranteed to be Mark Snow, btw. He has a certain style you get to recognise.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is Mark Snow's *Street War (In the Line of Duty)*, originally composed for the [film of the same name](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0104501/)

It was [released on an EP album](https://www.soundtrack.net/album/in-the-line-of-duty-mark-snow/) with three other songs by the same artist.